# Wamp (то бишь апач) на машине с iis

Tags: apache

Скажите, пожалуйста, уважаемая публика, как выйти из положения. Комп Windows 7 32 bit sp1 Visual studio dew Express 2013. Все заточено под разработку на asp.net, чем, собственно, и занимаюсь. Но  вот встал вопрос взять на поруки сайт на yii2. Поставил wamp, но он не  заводится, типа надо удялять iis, что делать я категорически не буду -- лучше пусть апач идет лесом. Но надо-таки взять на поруки сайт на yii2 и победить эту проблему. Премного благодарен.

Comment: @LutiyCsharp, самым грамотным решением будет развернуть виртуалку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставь их на разные порты слушать. И всё. Собственно, другой проблемы у тебя нет, насколько помню, в остальном они живут мирно и друг другу ничего не портят. В Apache в файле `ports.conf` поменяй

```
Listen 80
```

на

```
Listen 8080
```

Comment: Да,Спасибо! Завел!Простите за неосведомленность-не нашел где поставить галку

Comment: нашел галку!